# WSO2 ESB API sending an empty payload to an endpoint

Tags: wso2-esb

I am basically making two POST calls in esb api. The first call is with content type as text . Next call is with content type as application/json. In both the cases I am constructing payload using payload mediator. After successfully execution of first call, second call is failing. I see that the request payload is empty while making the second call. I enabled wire logs and saw that the request body is empty while making second call though I am able to print the json payload of message context. Please let me know, if I am doing something wrong here.

Below is the code
The first call is
  `<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
    <text  xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">userName=$1&amp;password=$2&amp; domain=$3&amp;captcha=$4
    </text>
    </format>
    <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.swmUser')"     xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.swmPassword1')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.domain')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <arg evaluator="xml"expression="get-property('uri.var.captcha')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="text/plain"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="text/plain"/>
    <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
    <log level="full">
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="requestpayload" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <call>
    <endpoint key="swmLoginEP"/>
    </call>
    <property expression="//jsonObject//sessionId//text()"       name="sessionId" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="full">
    <property expression="get-property('sessionId')" name="sessionId" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING"   value="application/json"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.key')" name="attribute" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{"attributeNames": ["vehicleModelYear"]}
    </format>
    <args>
    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('attribute')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <header name="Accept" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
    <header expression="get-property('sessionId')" name="sessionId"   scope="transport" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="full">
    <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="request payload of get values" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <log>
        <property expression="$body" name="PAYLOAD" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <call>
    <endpoint key="swmAttributeValuesEP"/>
    </call>`

This second call is sending an empty request payload to the endpoint

Thanks,
Azim

Comment: Could you post your code? Without it, I doubt anyone could say what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Hello @MariaDeleva Good Day!  As per your request added the code. Please check.

Comment: Hi in your second payload factory you have an arg (with value get-property('attribute')) that is never used, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the query is done via GET and not POST (could explain the empty body).
Did you try to explicitly precise that you want to use post like this for instance

```
<property description="Force Post" name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2"
  type="STRING" value="POST"/>
```

Comment: I can see that the endpoint declaration has http method as post and when the call is made, esb is making a POST call, this I saw from wire logs